# Parsing gene expression value for a list of genes from GEO

Tags: gene-expression, geoquery

I am looking for the gene expression data in [GEO GSE15543](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE15543) with the following keywords,

```
(Pancreatic Beta Cells) AND "Homo sapiens"[porgn:__txid9606]
```

I would like to parse the gene expression value of a list of genes from all the samples reported in any particular study.I understand there are two different formats for downloading datasets, SOFT and MINiML.

I have downloaded the soft.gz file and I am using BioConductor to read the contents from soft file using the instructions given [here](https://mdozmorov.github.io/BIOS567/assets/presentation_Bioconductor/GEO.pdf) . The file has the content that I 'm looking for , I have checked the contents on the geo2r webpage. I'm still facing challenge in finding out how to fetch out the gene expression values for a list of genes. Any suggestions?

From the files that I download, I wish to parse the gene expression value and the Sample Title and Sample Description so that I can classify the values based on disease state and control state. Any suggestions on which format can be downloaded for the above-mentioned task?

Answer (score 1):

GEO provides a GUI for this (just click on the "Analyze with GEO2 button"), you can even check/download the R/Bioconductor code used for the analyses.

Basically you will create groups of samples to compare/contrast and R/Bioconductor will run behind the scenes. Here is a nice [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUPmGWS8ik0).